# How to use daterangepicker with only one calendar

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, daterangepicker

I am having trouble getting only one calendar to appear using the date range picker. I am not quite sure where to start with this as simply hiding the other calendar does not appear to work when you want to change the month.

I am trying to use the daterangepicker to create a streamlined, mobile-friendly  date range picker. One such way I can do that is to remove one of the calendars. This will allow me to have more room on the mobile version and will let me keep most of the important content in view on my website.

I am attempting to implement this using bootstrap 3. I am also using ASP.NET MVC for the back end.

[DateRangePicker github repo](https://github.com/dangrossman/daterangepicker)

Comment: If you are having issues with code, please show the code.

Comment: I just copy/pasted the code from the examples. There is nothing unique in what I have already done, so I did not consider it worthwhile to share.

Comment: If you don't share it, then you are essentially asking us to write a solution from scratch.  That can be viewed as a coding request, which is off topic.  If you are having a specific issue, you need to ask about that specific issue.  You said you are having trouble doing something, which means you tried stuff.  You need to show us what you tried.

Comment: There is a fork of dangrossman's plugin that includes a "left calendar only" mode: https://github.com/bryan0/bootstrap-daterangepicker. This commit (https://github.com/dangrossman/daterangepicker/commit/11bbbd51ffaf9500750694defaf2be4a749a5112) has all the info you need to get it working. The downside of using this is that it's based on a rather old version of the plugin, but it might do the job.

Answer (score -2):

DateRangePicker (select date ranges with a single extended Calendar). I will attach a link that will walk you through the process with an example.

```
using System;

namespace CustomWebControls
{
    [Serializable]
    public struct DateRange
    {
        public static readonly DateRange EMPTY = new DateRange();

        readonly DateTime from;
        readonly DateTime to;


        public DateRange(DateTime from, DateTime to)
        {
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
        }


        public DateTime From
        {
            get { return from; }
        }

        public DateTime To
        {
            get { return to; }
        }

        public TimeSpan TimeSpan
        {
            get
            {
                return to - from;
            }
        }

        public bool Contains(DateTime time)
        {
            return from <= time && time < to;
        }

        public DateRange Include(DateRange otherRange)
        {
            return Include(otherRange.From).Include(otherRange.To);
        }

        public DateRange Include(DateTime date)
        {
            if (date < from)
                return new DateRange(date, to);
            else if (date > to)
                return new DateRange(from, date);
            else 
                return this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a one day (24 hr) long DateRange starting at DateTime
        /// </summary>
        public static DateRange CreateDay(DateTime dateTime){
            return new DateRange(dateTime, dateTime.AddDays(1));
        }

        #region operators and overrides
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return from.GetHashCode() + 29*to.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
            if (!(obj is DateRange)) return false;
            DateRange dateRange = (DateRange) obj;
            if (!Equals(from, dateRange.from)) return false;
            if (!Equals(to, dateRange.to)) return false;
            return true;
        }


        public static bool operator == (DateRange d1, DateRange d2)
        {
            return d1.Equals(d2);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(DateRange d1, DateRange d2)
        {
            return !d1.Equals(d2);
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

DateRangePicker
This is the class that overrides Calendar. It has two properties, one for styling the selected DateRange and another to store the selected DateRange.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CustomWebControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An extended Calendar that can select DateRanges as well as Dates
    /// </summary>
    [DefaultProperty("Text")]
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:DateRangePicker runat="server"></{0}:DateRangePicker>")]
    public class DateRangePicker : Calendar
    {
        static readonly TableItemStyle defaultSelectedDateRangeStyle = new TableItemStyle();


        static DateRangePicker()
        {
            //initialise a default colour for defaultSelectedDateRangeStyle
            defaultSelectedDateRangeStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
        }

        TableItemStyle selectedDateRangeStyle = defaultSelectedDateRangeStyle;

        protected override void OnDayRender(TableCell cell, CalendarDay day)
        {
            if (SelectedDateRange.Contains(day.Date))
            {
                cell.ApplyStyle(selectedDateRangeStyle);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnSelectionChanged()
        {
            base.OnSelectionChanged();

            bool emptyDateRange = SelectedDateRange == DateRange.EMPTY;
            bool dateRangeAlreadyPicked = SelectedDateRange.TimeSpan.TotalDays > 1;

            if (emptyDateRange || dateRangeAlreadyPicked)
            {
                SelectedDateRange = DateRange.CreateDay(SelectedDate);
                //save this date as the first date in our date range
            }
            else
            {
                SelectedDateRange = 
                  SelectedDateRange.Include(DateRange.CreateDay(SelectedDate));
                //set the end date in our date range
            }
        }

        //DateRange gets stored in the viewstate since
        //it's a property that needs to persist across page requests.
        <Browsable(false)>
        public DateRange SelectedDateRange
        {
            get { return (DateRange) (ViewState["SelectedDateRange"]??DateRange.EMPTY); }
            set { ViewState["SelectedDateRange"] = value; }
        }

        //SelectedDateRangeStyle goes into a private
        //variable since this property is designed.
        [Category("Styles")]
        [Description("The Style that is aplied to cells within the selected Date Range")]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        [NotifyParentProperty(true)]
        [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
        public TableItemStyle SelectedDateRangeStyle
        {
            get { return selectedDateRangeStyle; }
            set { selectedDateRangeStyle = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

[enter link description here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13792/%2FArticles%2F13792%2FDateRangePicker-select-date-ranges-with-a-single-e)

Comment: I have added to the explanation to the link

Comment: The article you linked is unrelated to OP's daterangepicker plugin. That link is referring to a custom ASP control.